# I want to indent the text below the image

Tags: css

I want to indent the text below the image.
This is my original text.

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Morbi blandit vehicula diam vitae dictum. Nunc ut justo eu tellus scelerisque feugiat id non justo. Ut eu ex id orci congue euismod. In efficitur nisi sed ante molestie, malesuada tristique ex accumsan. Suspendisse non tempus sem, ut eleifend est. Cras bibendum mi non odio lacinia volutpat. Integer interdum nisi quis porta posuere. Nulla mollis, felis a auctor consectetur, leo orci venenatis magna, in eleifend quam lacus ac felis. Sed sodales neque a euismod pulvinar. Suspendisse non diam elementum arcu feugiat venenatis. Nulla pulvinar, est ut eleifend hendrerit, tortor ipsum mattis eros, non feugiat diam lacus accumsan metus. Suspendisse sollicitudin metus ac luctus consequat. Nulla eget elit tincidunt, finibus ipsum nec, congue dui. Curabitur ac scelerisque magna. Duis sagittis varius sapien ut porta. Quisque rhoncus dapibus ultrices.

Maecenas eu neque fermentum, sagittis ligula nec, dignissim nisi. Maecenas et lectus lobortis quam blandit porta. Praesent vel gravida ante. Phasellus eu elit vitae nisi vulputate condimentum vel sit amet eros. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Quisque non est sed magna ornare tristique. Etiam aliquam sapien eu tellus laoreet luctus. Aliquam viverra lectus quis metus mattis euismod. Aenean faucibus ultrices nibh. Fusce vestibulum mauris in pretium ultrices.

and i want to indent the first line of each paragraph

by the way there's an image above the paragraph.

this is my code

```
<div class="caption"><img src="/html/images/sample-image.png" alt="">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Morbi blandit vehicula diam vitae dictum. Nunc ut justo eu tellus scelerisque feugiat id non justo. Ut eu ex id orci congue euismod. In efficitur nisi sed ante molestie, malesuada tristique ex accumsan. Suspendisse non tempus sem, ut eleifend est. Cras bibendum mi non odio lacinia volutpat. Integer interdum nisi quis porta posuere. Nulla mollis, felis a auctor consectetur, leo orci venenatis magna, in eleifend quam lacus ac felis. Sed sodales neque a euismod pulvinar. Suspendisse non diam elementum arcu feugiat venenatis. Nulla pulvinar, est ut eleifend hendrerit, tortor ipsum mattis eros, non feugiat diam lacus accumsan metus. Suspendisse sollicitudin metus ac luctus consequat. Nulla eget elit tincidunt, finibus ipsum nec, congue dui. Curabitur ac scelerisque magna. Duis sagittis varius sapien ut porta. Quisque rhoncus dapibus ultrices. Maecenas eu neque fermentum, sagittis ligula nec, dignissim nisi. Maecenas et lectus lobortis quam blandit porta. Praesent vel gravida ante. Phasellus eu elit vitae nisi vulputate condimentum vel sit amet eros. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Quisque non est sed magna ornare tristique. Etiam aliquam sapien eu tellus laoreet luctus. Aliquam viverra lectus quis metus mattis euismod. Aenean faucibus ultrices nibh. Fusce vestibulum mauris in pretium ultrices.<br><br>
```

how can i solve this in css code?
can anyone solve my problem? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You didn't really need to include two whole paragraphs of lorem-ipsum.

Answer (score 2):

wrap both texts in `<p>` tags

```
<div class="caption">
    <img src="/html/images/sample-image.png" alt="">
    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
    <p>Maecenas eu neque </p>
</div>
```

It would be easier for you to apply css on them in future

Answer (score 1):

Here is the working [Pen](http://codepen.io/ranavc32/pen/PbVmLz) for you.

You need to write css for paragraph. For complete code take a look at Pen Link Please

```
p .paragraph{
 word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

Did it solve your problem ?

Answer (score 1):

**I would assume you want something simple like this?**

That question wasn't very descriptive. Nonetheless, I have made a complete example. Just run the snippet.

Mainly, the important part was this:

```
.indent {
  text-indent: 2em;
}
```

But I included extra styling to make the answer more complete.

```css
.caption-wrap {
  width: 400px;
  border: solid 2px #000;
  padding: 20px;
}

.caption-wrap p {
  margin: 0;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

.captioned-image {
  display: block;
  width: 300px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border: solid 2px #000;
}

.indent {
  text-indent: 2em;
}
```

```html
<div class="caption-wrap">
  <img class="captioned-image" src="https://static.pexels.com/photos/20974/pexels-photo.jpg" alt="Captioned Image">
  <p class="indent">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Morbi blandit vehicula diam vitae dictum. Nunc ut justo eu tellus scelerisque feugiat id non justo. Ut eu ex id orci congue euismod. In efficitur nisi sed ante molestie, malesuada tristique ex accumsan. Suspendisse non tempus sem, ut eleifend est. Cras bibendum mi non odio lacinia volutpat. Integer interdum nisi quis porta posuere. Nulla mollis, felis a auctor consectetur, leo orci venenatis magna, in eleifend quam lacus ac felis. Sed sodales neque a euismod pulvinar. Suspendisse non diam elementum arcu feugiat venenatis. Nulla pulvinar, est ut eleifend hendrerit, tortor ipsum mattis eros, non feugiat diam lacus accumsan metus. Suspendisse sollicitudin metus ac luctus consequat. Nulla eget elit tincidunt, finibus ipsum nec, congue dui. Curabitur ac scelerisque magna. Duis sagittis varius sapien ut porta. Quisque rhoncus dapibus ultrices.</p>

  <p class="indent">Maecenas eu neque fermentum, sagittis ligula nec, dignissim nisi. Maecenas et lectus lobortis quam blandit porta. Praesent vel gravida ante. Phasellus eu elit vitae nisi vulputate condimentum vel sit amet eros. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Quisque non est sed magna ornare tristique. Etiam aliquam sapien eu tellus laoreet luctus. Aliquam viverra lectus quis metus mattis euismod. Aenean faucibus ultrices nibh. Fusce vestibulum mauris in pretium ultrices.</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use the tab special character at the start of each line

Answer (score 0):

add image style like below and wrap each paragraph inside `<p>` tag

```
<style>
  .caption img{display:block}
</style>

<p>first paragraph</p>
<p>second paragraph</p>
...
```